# Change the Flutter desktop app window size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-desktop

I am trying to build a desktop app with flutter. I want to display the app window half the size of screen when login screen of the app is visible.

Is there a way to change the size of the App window programmatically? Actually  I am new to dart and flutter Please help me, I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Flutter for desktop app development is still in early stages and in technical preview. Which OS are you developing for? This is the [recent update](https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-and-desktop-3a0dd0f8353e) about ongoing development work in flutter desktop.

Comment: I was developing for MacOS.

Comment: Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61451163/how-to-set-default-size-of-macos-app-in-flutter) to be similar. Edit and Add MacOS to your question it will help you get better answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [window_size plugin](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/plugins/window_size) will let you find the size of the screen and resize the window.

Comment: Tried this and it still comes up same size. For example if the screen width originally starts as 800, and I set it to a minimum of 1000 with this plugin, it still starts at 800 then when I try and drag it then snaps to the specified 1000 and maintains it as the minimum from there on.

Comment: Setting the minimum size and setting the current size are not the same call. Also, the question here wasn't about minimum size.

Answer (score 5):

you can use [window_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager)

```dart
await windowManager.setSize(Size(800, 600));
```

or [desktop_window](https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_window)

```dart
 Size size = await DesktopWindow.getWindowSize();
 DesktopWindow.setWindowSize(Size(800,600));
 DesktopWindow.setFullScreen(true);
```